# best way to recognize a Free segment, hyperbole or a Polygon from segments, no java.awt

Tags: java, awt, polygon, store, segment

im working on a project and basically i have this thing that draw segments every time, this class segment i have 2 objects PointOnTheArea which show me the two ends of the segment in the plane:

```
public  class PointOnTheArea implements Point {

    private final double pointX;
    private final double pointY;


    public PointOnTheArea(double x, double y){
        this.pointY = y;
        this.pointX = x;
    }
    public double getX(){
        return pointX;
    }
    public double getY(){
        return pointY;
    }
}


public class Segment {

private PointOnTheArea startingPoint;
private PointOnTheArea endingPoint;
private final SegmentType segmentType; // It is just for straight or curve
private final int radius; // just for curve segments
private final Direction dir; // direction it was drawn, is only for the plane
private boolean isTaken = false; // it is already part of a polygon???
private final int size; // distance between points
private final Color myColor; // just the color of the line



public Segment(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, SegmentType type, Direction dir, int radius, Color myColor){
    this.segmentType = type;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.dir = dir;
    setSegment(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    this.myColor = myColor;
    this.size = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.pow(y2-y1,2));
}
```

and im looking to find a way to store this segments and differentiate them in polygons, hyperbole or free segments:

1. Hyperbola is a sequence of segments that have a junction point in common (starting point of a segment = endingPoint of another 1)
2. Polygon is a loop that is created between segments everyone shares his endingPoint with the startingPoint of the next one, you cannot have 2 endingPoing or 2 starting Points in common (note that a polygon could be created starting from the fourth element of a List of segments up to the last one, therefore the first ones three would become a separate hyperbola)
3. Free segments, i.e. segments that have been created but are not attached to any other segment

when I started the project I had thought of a LinkedList  but now I find it difficult to manage everything, as many borderline cases remain uncovered, do u have some ideas? i ll appreciate a lot <3

AND NO i cannot use java.awt

Comment: Can I clarify - when you say "hyperbola", you just mean a path that doesn't close off into a polygon?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem right man, maybe I have the wrong term

Comment: Yeah, you definitely have the wrong term.  So you could make a `Path` class that contains a `List` of points along with a `boolean` that says whether the path is closed.  Then your drawing could contain a `Set` of `Path` objects.  In the case where you have a bunch of disconnected segments, your `Path` objects each have just two points.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem maybe I don't get there but I still can't understand how I can understand when Im in the 3 cases, especially the case where I find myself drawing a list of consecutive segments that create a Polygon only starting from the n-th segment up to 'last

Comment: So in that case, you'd have two `Path` objects in your set - one for the polygon part and one for the separate part.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have thought about it these days but I think that your solution as much as the solutions I had thought of in recent weeks are functional but that do not take into account many borderline cases, the only thing that I really think can be the solution is a graph with oriented weights, the only way to represent a closed area is to represent it as a cycle where the first and last node coincide, but idk im scared to do it

Comment: Then you need to mention what the borderline cases are that you think are difficult.